# Why is my query not returning data when the condition in the where clause is true?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the data in my table:

```
NAME    ADDRESS     GENDER  SID        
shadab  hyderabad   male    a16046
```

So why does my query return no data, when the condition is true?

```
select * from voters where sid='a16046'
```

Comment: I've updated the question on the assumption you were showing the table contents not the result of the query you showed - otherwise there wouldn't be an issue to ask about. What is the column data type? What does `select dump(sid)` from voters show - I suspect trailing spaces in the column value...

Comment: try using like operator with % on each side  '%a16046%' to see if there is some kind of whitespace char around it. Else, maybe the row is uncommitted?

Comment: "Why is my query not returning data when the condition in the where clause is true?" Because the where clause **is not true** even though you think it is. There must be some discrepancy between the data in the table and the value in your query. As Alex suggests, `DUMP(sid)` could identify non printing characters or other things.

Comment: You could have a row level policy. Try select * from DBA_POLICIES where object_name='VOTERS';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
select * from voters where TRIM(sid)='a16046'

OR

select * from voters where RTRIM(LTRIM(sid))='a16046'
```

Thanks:-)